# App Store Error "There was an unexpected error with your preview."

Tags: unity-game-engine, mobile, app-store

I am trying to upload my app to the app store and I have everything in place. However, when I try to submit my app for review I get the following error message:

[There as an unexpected error with your preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yRbC.png)

Can anyone help me with this? I checked everything and all seems to be fine.

Comment: Check this solution, this will likely help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73313352/app-store-screenshots-screenshot-uploads-in-progress-error-appscreenshotse

Answer (score 5):

There was a hidden screenshot that for some reason was not appearing. I closed the app store tab and opened it again and it was there. When I removed the screenshot that had an error I was able to submit my app.

Answer (score 1):

I have the error because I have just uploaded three screenshots. Adding one more screenshot fix this error for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use Safari. I had this error with Chrome, tried everything and nothing worked. It worked on Safari after a couple of times, but eventually it succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

i have solved this problem, use safari, and reload appstore connect, and you can submit for review

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I had to do to solve it:

1. Upload all my images
2. Open the Media Manager by clicking "View All Sizes in Media Manager"
3. Delete all images that were grey with a cloud icon on them (meaning they're "processing" indefinitely)
4. Upload multiple copies of the missing images until I filled all 10 slots
5. Switch back to the prepare for release screen
6. Repeat from #3, alternating between the two screens until there are no grey cloud images left

I think I went back and forth 5-6 times just reuploading everything. What an absolutely awful experience.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was a problem with app preview but in other than main language.

I needed to scroll through all supported languages of my app and find problematic clip.