# Unable to submit app vid preview to AppStore

Tags: swift, app-store

Disclaimer: I am aware that there is a SO question regarding this but unfortunately the solution there does not seem to work here. Also it seems as though he/she was trying to upload photos and this is a video. I'm not sure if it makes a difference.

This is the question I am referring to: [App Store Error "There was an unexpected error with your preview."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63546125/app-store-error-there-was-an-unexpected-error-with-your-preview)

And this is my problem

So this is the error:

```
 Unable to Submit for Review
The items below are required to start the review process:
There was an unexpected error with your preview.
```

[image]

I have tried to delete and reupload, refresh, etc multiple times to no avail.

1. I created the vid recording the simulator screen
2. Converted vid to correct resolution using ffmpeg in CLI.
3. Tried to upload x times

Comment: Can you send me the video file?

Comment: @aheze Sure what's your email?

Comment: Do you have google drive? It would be easier to share a link

Comment: Sure here is the link the both of the vids I was trying to upload 
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1i8udx_x3AV2n0k0bJQGGBk7btnzjpif7?usp=sharing

Comment: "You need access" can you set the sharing permissions to "Anyone with the link"?

Comment: Sorry I thought I did, you should be clear now

Comment: It looks alright. The only thing is that it's 31 seconds, not 30 - try trimming it. If that doesn't work, try converting to a different format like MOV.

Comment: Unfortunately that didnt work. I converted to .mov and even trimmed it well below 30 seconds, to about 20 just for testing and same result. I'll try a little later and/or contact Apple support, this seems like its in their hands.